# Unable to establish a connection to any database host

Tags: php, mysql, database, phabricator

I've been trying to install Phabricator on Centos 6.8 and Ubuntu 14.04. On both attempts, when configuring MySQL with phab, I get the following errors:

```
    EXCEPTION: (PhabricatorClusterStrandedException) Unable to establish a connection to any database host (while trying "phabricator_config"). All masters and replicas are completely unreachable. at [<phabricator>/src/infrastructure/storage/lisk/PhabricatorLiskDAO.php:140]
arcanist(head=master, ref.master=fad85844314b), phabricator(head=master, ref.master=4dadad53ae5d), phutil(head=master, ref.master=086df1ba443c)
    #0 PhabricatorLiskDAO::raiseUnreachable(string) called at [<phabricator>/src/infrastructure/storage/lisk/PhabricatorLiskDAO.php:111]
    #1 PhabricatorLiskDAO::newClusterConnection(string, string, string) called at [<phabricator>/src/infrastructure/storage/lisk/PhabricatorLiskDAO.php:66]
    #2 PhabricatorLiskDAO::establishLiveConnection(string) called at [<phabricator>/src/infrastructure/storage/lisk/LiskDAO.php:1008]
    #3 LiskDAO::establishConnection(string) called at [<phabricator>/src/infrastructure/storage/lisk/LiskDAO.php:516]
    #4 LiskDAO::loadRawDataWhere(string, string)
    #5 call_user_func_array(array, array) called at [<phabricator>/src/infrastructure/storage/lisk/LiskDAO.php:476]
    #6 LiskDAO::loadAllWhere(string, string) called at [<phabricator>/src/infrastructure/env/PhabricatorConfigDatabaseSource.php:19]
    #7 PhabricatorConfigDatabaseSource::loadConfig(string) called at [<phabricator>/src/infrastructure/env/PhabricatorConfigDatabaseSource.php:7]
    #8 PhabricatorConfigDatabaseSource::__construct(string) called at [<phabricator>/src/infrastructure/env/PhabricatorEnv.php:249]
    #9 PhabricatorEnv::buildConfigurationSourceStack(boolean) called at [<phabricator>/src/infrastructure/env/PhabricatorEnv.php:95]
    #10 PhabricatorEnv::initializeCommonEnvironment(boolean) called at [<phabricator>/src/infrastructure/env/PhabricatorEnv.php:75]
    #11 PhabricatorEnv::initializeScriptEnvironment(boolean) called at [<phabricator>/scripts/init/lib.php:22]
    #12 init_phabricator_script(array) called at [<phabricator>/scripts/init/init-setup.php:12]
    #13 require_once(string) called at [<phabricator>/scripts/sql/manage_storage.php:5]
```

I've been following this installation guide: https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/configuration_guide/

I've also attempted to follow others online, with no success. 
The command attempted was

> ./bin/storage upgrade

I've also attempted

> ./bin/storage upgrade --user  --password

And other commands such as setting the host or user on ./bin/config, but all seem to cause the same error.

I'm not sure what to do at this point, I've been playing with every config I can find.

Comment: This error means that it cannot connect to MySQL. Did you verify mysql is actually running? Can you connect manually with the `mysql` client?

Comment: I've been able to log in with 'mysql -u root -p' and I've checked the services and it seems that mysql is in fact running and listening on port 3306.

Comment: try restarting the server.. could be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was hitting the same exception today while running 'bin/config set mysql.host localhost'. I suspect that there might be a bug with the latest phabricator code (as of 2016/11/23), so I switched to an earlier snapshot and things work just fine.